# How do i join two tables in a database using MySQL with specific names

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have a movies database using mysql in xampp. 
It has 3 tables

`movies(movieid(PK), title, rating, genre, release_date),
actors(actorid(PK), firstname,lastname,gender, date_of_birth), and actorsmovies(actorid(PK),movieid(pk).`

I have to Display all fields from the movies where Michael J. Fox is the actor. How do i join the two tables that will show me only movies michael j fox was in? the actorsmovies has constraints on it.

example: Ive tried a million combinations but this is an example

`select firstname,lastname,title from actors where firstname,lastname = 'Michael J','Fox' join actorsmovies on actors.actorid = actorsmovies.actorid join movies on actorsmovies.movieid = movies.movieid;`

Comment: don't try to get cute with the syntax. `where firstname = 'michael' and lastname='fox'`

Comment: select firstname,lastname,title from actors join actorsmovies on actors.actorid = actorsmovies.actorid join movies on actorsmovies.movieid = movies.movieid; this is what i type to show all actors and the movies but i dont know how to show just the movies michael j fox was in

Comment: The order of the syntax matters... Just add/move the where clause to the end Order is (SELECT, FROM, JOIN, WHERE, GROUP BY, HAVING, ORDER BY) notice the WHERE is after all the from statements  you have yours inbetween a join I believe.

Comment: thanks @Marc B. i got it to work!

Comment: Thanks for replying @xQbert, that fixed the problem. I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
select firstname,lastname,title 
from actors 
  where firstname,lastname = 'Michael J','Fox' 
join actorsmovies 
  on actors.actorid = actorsmovies.actorid 
join movies on actorsmovies.movieid = movies.movieid;
```

and you need

```
select firstname,lastname,title 
from actors 
join actorsmovies 
  on actors.actorid = actorsmovies.actorid 
join movies on actorsmovies.movieid = movies.movieid
where firstname = 'Michael J' and lastname 'Fox';
```

Simply put, the where clause has to be after the joins and before an order by group by and having.  I also recommend being more explicit on your where clause and spelling out the and just for readability.

Now if your joins where outer joins you may need to mvoe the limit to the critiera

say in this example you want all movies and you want to "hilight" the ones with michael J fox...  the right join here returnss all the movies titles and firstname,lastname will not be blank when it's michael J. Fox. otherwise it will be blank!

```
select firstname,lastname,title 
from actors 
join actorsmovies 
  on actors.actorid = actorsmovies.actorid 
and actors.firstname = 'Michael J' and actors.lastname 'Fox';
right join movies on actorsmovies.movieid = movies.movieid;
```